# xcode distribution Provisioning profile "None"

Tags: iphone, ios7, sdk, xcode5, xcode6

In xcode 6:
I have problem while submitting app to app store that when i archive apps,it show me provisioning profile "none" as show in below image.

[image]

I have install all certificate in keychain as well.

can you please tell me how it show me such result.

In xcode 5 : it will give me "No identity found"

Comment: Check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24924809/the-file-myapp-app-couldnt-be-opened-because-you-dont-have-permission-to-vi

Answer (score 2):

In my case this issue started with the recent Xcode update. For whatever reason, Xcode's automatic signing was failing to select the correct profile when archiving.

After sinking a few hours into toggling things, cleaning things and refreshing things, I simply disabled the "Automatically manage signing" setting and did it the old fashioned way.

That is, create relevant provisioning profiles in the [Developer Console](https://developer.apple.com) and select them manually in the "Signing" sections that appear after disabling automatic signing.

Comment: works for signing and releasing your app. but doesn't work as it should. i have an iCloud container associated with my app ID and after updating to XCode 10 it doesn't work anymore. I've tried everything, revoked and deleted certs. and profiles and recreated them. automatic signing works and runs perfectly fine on my phone (directly from xcode to my iPhone 8 connected with cable). but when I try to archive the app the Profile is always NONE. when I sign the app manually and submit it to iTunes, the iCloud container is missing. how apple frustrates me with each update ..

Comment: Ah yeah sorry, I’m not using iCloud container, so this is working for me. I’d assume you could potentially fix this by making the appropriate configurations in dev console and Xcode, but YMMV.

Comment: Same problem here @Nexus. Since Xcode10 I cant get my testflight working properly with correct entitlements.  Any help?

Comment: @DavidGallardo nothing yet T_T I'll post my answer here if I find it. this is incredibly frustrating, iCloud container works in dev environment on my phone, but not in TestFlight. no documentation, no help no nothing .. I don't even know what to do and my client needs this ASAP.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following in xcode6:

```
1. Xcode->preferences->accounts->View Details->click the refresh button
2. click your project->click Targets->click build settings tab->choose your distribute provisioning profile in Code Signing
```

Then, try to submit your app again.