# Xcode 6.1 - Nib couldn’t be opened because you don’t have permission to view it

Tags: ios, xcode

I have this really weird problem. After upgrading to Xcode 6.1 I get these error on some random nibs:

```
/* com.apple.ibtool.errors */
/Users/xxx/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/WorkspaceInfinity-fufemvkrqrpfbmcwcrcicvoxtmvj/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/CoreFramework.embeddedframework/Resources/yyy.nib: 
error: The file “yyy.nib” couldn’t be opened because you don’t have permission to view it.
        Failure Reason: You don’t have permission.
        Recovery Suggestion: To view or change permissions, select the item in the Finder and choose File > Get Info.
        Underlying Errors:
            Description: The operation couldn’t be completed. Permission denied
            Failure Reason: Permission denied
```

I'm using kstenerud [iOS Universal Framework solution](https://github.com/kstenerud/iOS-Universal-Framework). If I go back to Xcode 6.0 the problem disappear. I tried all the common solutions like delete derived datas, clean the product, re-add these files on the project.

If I look into the App package I see that instead of these nibs I have an alias to them (which is not working). Seems like the Copy Bundle Resources step might be broken.

Comment: Refer to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50167291/6521116) with a good summary of this issue.

Answer (score 6):

Try this:

Select **Project**(under **target**)--> **Build Settings**-->**Build Options**

set **Compiler for C/C++/Objective-C** to **Default compiler(Apple LLVM 6.0)**

[image]

Comment: This worked for me, thanks @mavericks. But what's the concept behind this? Thanks.

Comment: I don't know that, if you get the answer then let me know too, and thanks for the points.

Answer (score 0):

In Xcode Go to Build Settings.

In the "Strip NIB Files" option choose "NO".

That should solve it.

Comment: I already tried that solution but the only thing that I could achieve in that way is that I can compile. When then I use the nib in my program it crashes telling me that it can't find it.

Comment: @AlbertoSchiariti , were you able to solve this somehow?

Comment: Nope. Actually I had to download an old version of XCode in order to succesfully compile. I hope they will fix it in the next version (if there is something to fix in it)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Probably I'll have to do the same for now and then migrate to Apple-provided template.

Comment: Looks like it doesn't happen in my case. Probably will have to convert to Apple-provided template then.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same or very similar problem, but building in older Xcode didn't help. I had to switch framework project to https://github.com/jverkoey/iOS-Framework and errors were gone. Probably Xcode 6.1 changed some build settings or something like this.