# Unable to Write to Documents Directory after upgrading to Xcode 7

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

After Upgrading to Xcode 7, I tried to re-run my app and I am now getting the following error:

You don’t have permission to save the file “PDF” in the folder “Documents”.

I can't figure out what the problem is, someone pls help.  I've already tried clearing derived data and cleaning my project.

I saw this thread, but none of the solutions helped -> [Error while build project Xcode says: "you don't have permission"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27355361/error-while-build-project-xcode-says-you-dont-have-permission)

UPDATED - Here's my code:

```
var docsDirNew: NSURL!
var currentPath: String!

docsDirNew = NSFileManager.defaultManager().URLsForDirectory(.DocumentDirectory, inDomains: .UserDomainMask)[0]

let unknown = docsDirNew.URLByAppendingPathComponent(dirPath)
currentPath = "\(unknown)"


var error: NSError?

    do {
        try filemgr.createDirectoryAtPath(currentPath, withIntermediateDirectories: true, attributes: nil)

        Scripts.logClass(className, message: "fileOperationsCreateDirectory >> CREATE Directory SUCCESS")
    }
    catch let error1 as NSError {

        error = error1

        Scripts.logClass(className, message: "fileOperationsCreateDirectory >> CREATE Directory FAILED >> \(error!.localizedDescription)")
    }
```

Comment: Update your question with your code for getting the Documents folder reference and trying to write a file to it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This line:

```
currentPath = "\(unknown)"
```

should have never worked. It should be:

```
currentPath = unknown.path
```

Your original code depended on the arbitrary implementation of the `NSURL description` method.

Comment: To be honest, I didn't have that line initially.  I just added it trying to debug why my program was crashing after upgrading to XCode 7 because I noticed stringByAppendingPathComponent was deprecated.  Either way, thanks a lot for you help cos that line worked.  Now I know what to use to get the string value of my path.