# Is there a way to run xcode 14 on macOS Sonoma?

Tags: xcode

Is there a way to run xcode 14 on macOS Sonoma? I accidentally upgraded the system and cannot publish the official project

Comment: You can't. You need to Install the Xcode 15-beta from the official website https://developer.apple.com/xcode/ and you can still publish your project.

Comment: @OMiShah You can't submit apps to the App Store using beta software.

Comment: @HangarRash, my mistake, i misunderstood publish with building/release. And you're right, can't be published on app store.

Answer (score 79):

Starting the binary directly did not work for me, the system would still refuse to run the app.

What did work however was to

- Right click the app and select "Show Package Contents"
- Navigate to `Contents` folder
- Open the `Info.plist` file
- Alter `CFBundleVersion` from `21815` to `22265`
- Save change
- Right app and select "Open"

If you get an error after choosing "Open" for the first time, wait a few seconds and try again, the system (or Finder) seems to cache `Info.plist` data and may take a moment to realize that it has changed.

You should see the install screen that is installing the built-in SDKs and allows you to download additional ones.

Comment: This worked for me, but it was in version.plist and not in Info.plist. I am using XCode 14.3.1.

Comment: @LeonardoG I didn't touch the `version.plist` file, it it still contains the original version, just the `Info.plist` file and that worked fine for me and I'm also using Xcode 14.3.1 I didn't even consider touching the version file as that's not a standard file you find in macOS app bundles and thus I would not expect the Finder or the LaunchServices to even look at its content, yet those surely look at the standard `Info.plist` found in every app bundle. But if it works by just changing the version file, so be it.

Comment: my Info.plist file was in binary format and not easily editable, for some reason.

Comment: You saved my time. Thanks

Comment: Mine was also in a binary format, I was able to work around this by coping the preview in finder (which was still plaintext) and then overwriting the binary version with the plaintext version before saving when updating the CFBundleVersion

Comment: `sudo chmod 755 Info.plist` gives you read-write permission for the file.

Comment: Converting back and forth from/to binary/XML: https://discussions.apple.com/thread/1768480?sortBy=best

Comment: When I try that, starting Xcode 14 shows a license agreement dialog.  I click Agree, authenticate when requested, but the dialog remains.  Clicking Agree again does nothing, and all I can do is quit.

Comment: Used this command to set it quicker. Replace Xcode.app path with your install location /usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c "Set CFBundleVersion 22265 " /Applications/Xcode_14.3.1.app/Contents/Info.plist

Comment: Mine was also in binary format, but I installed BBEdit 15 and this allowed me to edit and save the binary format directly.

Comment: This worked for me, but I had to first drag Xcode.app out of the Applications folder to somewhere else (my Home folder), then edit the Info.plist file, then drag the Xcode.app back into the Applications folder.

Comment: You're my personal Jesus. But yeah, as @YaronBudowski said, you need to convert it from binary to XML, edit it, then convert it back to binary using the tools described in the link he shared.

Answer (score 31):

You could run old Xcode via Terminal command:

```
/Applications/Xcode_14.app/Contents/MacOS/Xcode
```

This will bypass macOS limitation.

Comment: After many warnings it ends with the error `The application cannot be opened for an unexpected reason, error=Error Domain=NSOSStatusErrorDomain Code=-10664 "kLSIncompatibleApplicationVersionErr: The app is incompatible with the current OS" UserInfo={_LSLine=4106, _LSFunction=_LSOpenStuffCallLocal}`

Comment: The application cannot be opened for an unexpected reason, error=Error Domain=NSOSStatusErrorDomain Code=-10664 "kLSIncompatibleApplicationVersionErr: The app is incompatible with the current OS" UserInfo={_LSLine=4106, _LSFunction=_LSOpenStuffCallLocal}

Comment: Just run command again after installing the Command Line Tools for 14 Xcode.

Comment: @VasiliyAnisimov You cannot install them, it will say the system is too new for this version.

Comment: @Ivan Xcode itself offers to install them after the first startup attempt.

Comment: ok, you were right, I was trying to run the images downloaded via xcodes app - dont know why but system reported them as corrupted. however once i downloaded from official apple site via browser I was able to run

Answer (score 11):

This problem is similar to what was encountered last year when attempting to use Xcode 13 on macOS Ventura. Please check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74192401/19500804) to resolve the issue. As mentioned you can directly launch it from the finder or terminal you need to select the Xcode app that you want to use and then:

> Right-click on the app and click on **Show Package Contents** > **Open
> Contents** > **Open MacOS** > and **launch Xcode**.

Or you can also use a single-run script to fix the problem which is mentioned in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74500488/19500804)

Answer (score 9):

You can open Xcode 14 in Sonoma by following below Steps:

Step 1;
Download the Zip from here - https://developer.apple.com/services-account/download?path=/Developer_Tools/Xcode_14.3.1/Xcode_14.3.1.xip

Step 2 - You would notice a disabled Xcode. Right click on it and go to "Show package content"

[image]

Step 3: Click on the Mac OS console would start and then the Xcode.
It could ask to install dependent watch and other Simulators. Install them and it is good to go for use.

[image]

After this you can see the Xcode icon like below. Click on it to open Xcode
[image]

Answer (score 1):

**Quick solution for people who move to a new Mac:**

I don't need XCode at all, only Command Line Tools 14.
People like me who have a new MBP M3 cannot downgrade Sonoma,
but this works fine if you still have an older machine with CLT 14 installed:

- Zip CLT 14 together on the old machine with Finder / Compress
- Transfer the ZIP to /Library/Developer on the Sonoma box
- Unzip, and then
  `sudo xcode-select --switch /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools`

Now I can do my PySide6 builds again without headaches.

Comment: What is wrong with this quick work-around?

Comment: Not the downvoter, but it potentially requires installing another OS, and doesn't install Xcode 14 itself (people might want this due to Apple changing the view crash log behavior on us devs)