# macOS app has broken UI on Sonoma (macOS 14) but only when buiding it with Xcode 15

Tags: xcode, macos, user-interface, appkit, macos-sonoma

When I build my UI application with Xcode 15 and run the app on macOS 14 (Sonoma), the UI is largely missing in several views. The UI looks fine when running that same build on any system prior to macOS 14. The UI also looks fine when building with Xcode 14.3.1 and running the app on macOS 14. It's just the combination of Xcode 15 and macOS 14 that causes this problem.

As a workaround I keep building the app with Xcode 14.3.1, even though I'm on Sonoma and Xcode 14.3.1 doesn't even support Sonoma, but using [this trick](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77243790/15809) I was able to get it working anyway. This solves the problem for now but is not really a long term fix, since at some point in the future, upgrading to an newer Xcode version will become unavoidable.

Answer (score 7):

First of all, the issue is not related to the Xcode version but to the SDK version. Xcode 15 ships with a macOS 14 SDK, while Xcode 14.3.1 only ships with a macOS 13 SDK.

The reason for the issue is a change in AppKit, that will only affect apps linked against the macOS 14 SDK and only when also running on macOS 14, which explains why the problem does not appear when running on older macOS versions or building with an older SDK.

The change is mentioned in the macOS 14 AppKit release notes:

> In macOS 14, AppKit is exposing the clipsToBounds property of NSView.
>
> For applications linked against the macOS 14 SDK, the default value of this property is false. Apps linked against older SDKs default to true. Some classes, like NSClipView, continue to default to true. The change in defaults recognizes that it is vastly easier to reason about clipping a view’s descendants than it is to unclip a view’s ancestors.

Source: [AppKit 14 Releas Notes](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/macos-release-notes/appkit-release-notes-for-macos-14#NSView)

This mainly affects subclasses of `NSView` that implement their own `drawRect:(NSRect)dirtyRect` method. The `dirtyRect` describes the array of screen that needs redrawing and it is passed to the method, so any drawing code can limit its drawing operations to that area only.

This is just a speed optimization, as always redrawing the entire view will also produce correct results, but it may cause the view to draw way more than would really been necessary. That's why many simple views don't even consider the `dirtRect` and just always redraw everything but that way they waste CPU/GPU resources for nothing.

So far `clipsToBounds` has always been true. This means that prior to calling this method, the system would clip the `dirtyRect` to the bounds of the view. So any `dirtRect` ever passed to the view was either a sub-rect of the view's current bounds or, in the worst case, equaled the bounding rect, in which case the entire view had to be redrawn. But that's no longer the case by default, meaning parts of the `dirtyRect` can lie outside the view's bounding box or the `dirtyRect` can also be way bigger than the entire view and thus completely enclose it.

When the system wants to update the whole window, it can just use a `dirtRect` that encloses the entire window, or larger chunks of it, and without clipping to bounds, the following code will cause the UI problem:

```
- (void)drawRect:(NSRect)dirtyRect
{
    [[NSColor ...] set];
    NSRectFill(dirtyRect);
}
```

This is also addressed by Apple in the release notes:

> Filling the dirty rect of a view inside of -drawRect. A fairly common pattern is to simply rect fill the dirty rect passed into an override of NSView.draw(). The dirty rect can now extend outside of your view’s bounds. This pattern can be adjusted by filling the bounds instead of the dirty rect, or by setting clipsToBounds = true.

Source: [AppKit 14 Releas Notes](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/macos-release-notes/appkit-release-notes-for-macos-14#NSView)

So far this fill instruction would only fill either the entire view or a sub-rect of it. But with no clipping anymore, it may fill large parts of its superview or even the entire window!

Apple makes two suggestions how to fix that but IMHO those are both are bad suggestions.

1. Re-enabling `clipToBounds` will solve the problem, as then `dirtyRect` is clipped again and you get the old behavior. However, keep in mind, that your custom drawing view can also be used within Interface Builder (in a XIB file) and in Interface Builder, `Clips Bounds` is a settable property, so somebody using your view, not knowing that it depends on that clipping behavior (as that's not really expected to be the case), may set the property incorrectly and then having no idea why the entire UI is gone again.
2. Always filling the entire bounds will, of course, work correctly, but that's simply overdoing. The `dirtyRect` may also be smaller than the view's bounds and there is no reason why you need to fill a huge area of screen if only a small portion of it really needs redrawing.

IMHO the best solution is to simply clip to bounds yourself:

```
- (void)drawRect:(NSRect)dirtyRect
{
    NSRect clippedRect = NSIntersectionRect(dirtyRect, self.bounds);
    [[NSColor ...] set];
    NSRectFill(clippedRect);
}
```

`clippedRect` is a rect describing the area that is common to both, your bounds and the `dirtyRect`. In the worst case, it will equal your bounds, but it will never get bigger than that. And in the best case, it will be a small subarea of your bounds and then only that subarea requires filling.

Comment: Thank you very much @Mecki, this was a very helpful answer. I encountered the same kind of broken UI in several places of our app after building with Xcode 15 / macOS 14 SDK. In addition to fixing `drawRect:` overrides, I found we needed to set `view.clipsToBounds=YES` in some other cases even where we did not override `drawRect:`. Specifically, 1) where subviews can legitimately be drawn outside the bounds, such as when animating a view in or out of another - and 2) other cases where clipping is needed, probably because of failure to ensure that subview dimensions are properly defined.

Comment: @LarryW You are correct. Apple themselves indirectly even acknowledge that there are situations were enabling `clipsToBounds` is unavoidable and they enable it by default for `NSClipView`, which makes sense, as the whole purpose of such a view is to clip its subviews, which it would simply not do anymore without that property being enabled. `NSClipView` is rarely ever used on its own but it's a part of every `NSScrollView` and ensures that views which are completely or partly outside the visible area of the scroll view get clipped correctly.

Comment: @LarryW , Mecki,  Thanks for details answer.
I am also facing similar issue when build Mac app with Xcode15 and Sonoma. NSColor is not properly rendering. Thanks in advance.

Comment: @AbhijeetBarge You should ask that as an own question, as that makes it easier to answer it and also ask follow up questions. Also you may want to explain in more detail what exactly "not properly" means (no color at all, wrong color, how wrong) or even provide a short piece of code.

Comment: @AbhijeetBarge If you do create a new question, please include the link to it here so others can follow the trail. It's quite possible your issue is different because `clipsToBounds` is not related to rendering colors, but rather the location of view's content. That said, perhaps not clipping the content is impacting some custom rendering you do and thus it appears that the colors are incorrect because they are "mixing" with colors above and below in the view hierarchy (i.e. the alpha channel value and location of the colors drawn is producing an unexpected display).

Comment: I'm having what is undoubtedly a related problem, in which views don't draw at all if the code is compiled with XCode14 and run on Sonoma. The code works fine on Sonoma if built with an earlier XCode. ClipsToBounds doesn't seem to be involved: the views just appear solid black regardless. These are using CGContext, however. ImageViews draw OK, NSPanels draw OK.