# The file could not be opened becuase you dont have permission to view it

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

A project was working normally, but after i updated xcode to its latest version, i began having this error everytime i want to run the project on a real device :

```
The file could not be opened becuase you dont have permission to view it.
```

i tried all the solutions in this link: [Error while build project xcode says : "you don't have permission"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27355361/error-while-build-project-xcode-says-you-dont-have-permission)
but nothing worked, and the error is still there.
any idea what happened?
thanks

Comment: when does this error appear? in Xcode when you run on a device? or on the device itself? Did you check the logs of the device?

Comment: it appears on xcode when the run button is tapped

Comment: after the build was finished successfully? are you connect with a cable to the computer or using the wifi to install on the device?

Comment: connected with a cable

Comment: can you try to delete the derived data folder and clean one more time afterward?

Comment: and how do we delete the derived data folder

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/181947/discussion-between-catalina-t-and-mrj).

Answer (score 0):

If the project you download from the internet don't have the Executable file can make this.Last time ,I use the fllow method to solve it.

1. Open info.plist
2. Check the key "Executable file"'s value,its value should be this ${EXECUTABLE_NAME}.
3. clean->build->run

So when i changed it ${EXECUTABLE_NAME} this value then successfully.

Comment: i checked it , its ${EXECUTABLE_NAME} , the project isnt downloaded from the internet. nothing worked