# You don’t have permission to save the file while running Xcode 12.3 project in Mac OS 11.1

Tags: swiftui, xcode12, macos-big-sur

I am updated my Mac to MacOS 11.1 BigSur and Xcode to 12.3 to work on SwiftUI 2. But after creating empty project when I am trying to run it getting error as "You don’t have permission to save the file “4DA726C5-ABD7-49F5-A573-46DE3084E2A5” in the f…"

Please help me for the solution ..Thank You

[image]

Comment: What is iOS 11.1 BigSur?  macOS 11.1 BigSur?

Comment: Maybe it’s useful: https://stackoverflow.com/a/27355599/14733292

Comment: @ElTomato sorry it was just typo..corrected it

Answer (score -1):

I have resolved this issue by "sudo chmod 777 ~/Library/Logs;"