# Xcode says "you don’t have permission to view it." after copying an existing target

Tags: objective-c, xcode, xcode6

I have a project and it works fine. Then I had to make a different version, with the same functions and just need to modify some UI pictures and app name. So I copied the target, made some changes to the target settings, like product name, provisioning profile, preprocessor macros. But when I tried to run it, Xcode show me the dialog: "The file “SecondAppName” couldn’t be opened because you don’t have permission to view it."

I have tried:

- Repairing permissions using disk utility
- Cleaning my project
- Deleting derived data
- Changing compiler for c/c++/objective-c to Default compiler

But this issue continues to appear. I googled a whole day, but no useful solutions found.
Could some one help me? Thanks in advance!

P.S: the original target can run perfectly, the issue only appears on the new target.

Comment: I tried, but it doesn't make any difference.

Comment: Seems I encountered a very rare problem. I almost tried every solution I can find on google, but none helps.

Comment: Refer to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50167291/6521116) with a good summary of this issue.

Answer (score 1):

I had the very same problem with an app that I built hundred times and suddenly came with this error.

When I performed a project clean the app could build normally but if I tried to rebuild again right after the first build a message saying "The file “iRank Poker Timer” couldn’t be opened because you don’t have permission to view it".

I solved the problem by deleting the second target I've created and duplicate the main target again. Then I edited those files:

- project.pbxproj
- iRank Timer copy.xcscheme (That I renamed to "iRank Timer Lite.xcscheme")
- xcschememanagement.plist
- iRank Timer copy-Info.plist (That I renamed to "iRank Timer copy-Info.plist")

and replaced all "copy" word occurrences for "Lite".

This completely solved my problem and I never got that annoying message again.

Answer (score 0):

The below link has provided multiple options to rename the app name. Pl. check if it can help you
[How to change the name of an iOS app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/238980/how-to-change-the-name-of-an-ios-app)
we have tried renaming the app name by modifying the bundle identifer and restarting the xcode. it has worked for us without any issue