# Running app from Xcode 6: "The file couldn’t be opened because you don’t have permission"

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

I have a Swift project in Xcode 6.3.2 which consists of an app project using a framework subproject. Everything builds and links fine. It is only when Xcode attempts to launch the app file, this error appears: **"The file “AppName” couldn’t be opened because you don’t have permission to view it."** The project has built and run successfully before.

I realize there are other questions like this one already. I have read and tried all the solutions given in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24924809/the-file-myapp-app-couldnt-be-opened-because-you-dont-have-permission-to-vi) and several others.

I tried:

- Clean
- Clean Build Folder
- Delete Derived Data
- Checking the permissions of the directories and app file itself
- Setting Build Settings > Compiler for C/C++/Objective-C to Default compiler
- Setting Build Settings > Architectures to Standard Architectures
- Editing info.plist, setting Executable file to ${EXECUTABLE_NAME} and Bundle name to ${PRODUCT_NAME}
- Replacing info.plist with a new one

Are there any other possible causes and solutions to this error that anyone has come across?

Comment: Update [Xcode](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/xcode/id497799835?mt=12) to 6.3.2?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @DanielStorm. I just updated, along with a restart and another clean build. The problem is still there.

Comment: Refer to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50167291/6521116) with a good summary of this issue.