# Issues with read file permission Swift & Firebase - mobile not simulator

Tags: swift, firebase, swift3, permissions, firebase-storage

I am attempting to upload a video from a custom UICollection that accesses the users videos. When I attempt to upload the URL to firebase, I get the following error:

```
Body file is unreachable: /var/mobile/Media/DCIM/103APPLE/IMG_3002.MOV
  Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=257 "The file “IMG_3002.MOV” couldn’t be opened because you don’t have permission to view it." UserInfo={NSURL=file:///var/mobile/Media/DCIM/103APPLE/IMG_3002.MOV, NSFilePath=/var/mobile/Media/DCIM/103APPLE/IMG_3002.MOV, NSUnderlyingError=0x17024b790 {Error Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=1 "Operation not permitted"}}
```

I am a little confused as to why this is occuring, b/c when I print out the url of the video I get:

```
file:///var/mobile/Media/DCIM/103APPLE/IMG_3002.MOV
```

&& my info.plist looks like this
[image]

Here is the upload code:

```
videosFolder.child("\(nsuid).mov").putFile(self.videoURLToUpload, metadata: nil, completion: { (metadata, error) in
                if error != nil {
                    print("we Had an Error!: \(String(describing: error))")
                } else {
                    print("we uploaded the video correctly!!!")
                }
            })
```

&& just in-case here is the where I am fetching the videos

```
struct Media {
    var image:UIImage?
    var videoURL:NSURL?
}

var mediaArray = [Media]()

func grabPhotos(){
    let imgManager = PHImageManager.default()

    let requestOptions = PHImageRequestOptions()
    requestOptions.isSynchronous = true
    requestOptions.deliveryMode = .highQualityFormat

    let fetchOptions = PHFetchOptions()
    fetchOptions.sortDescriptors = [NSSortDescriptor(key: "creationDate", ascending: false)]
    if let fetchResult : PHFetchResult = PHAsset.fetchAssets(with: .video, options: fetchOptions) {


        if fetchResult.count > 0 {
            for i in 0..<fetchResult.count{
                var mediaItem = Media()
                //Used for fetch Image//
                imgManager.requestImage(for: fetchResult.object(at: i) as PHAsset , targetSize: CGSize(width: 400, height: 400), contentMode: .aspectFit, options: requestOptions, resultHandler: {
                    image, error in
                    let imageOfVideo = image! as UIImage
                    mediaItem.image = imageOfVideo;
                    //Used for fetch Video//
                    imgManager.requestAVAsset(forVideo: fetchResult.object(at: i) as PHAsset, options: PHVideoRequestOptions(), resultHandler: {(avAsset, audioMix, info) -> Void in
                        if let asset = avAsset as? AVURLAsset {
                            let videoData = NSURL(string: "\(asset.url)")
                            let duration : CMTime = asset.duration
                            let durationInSecond = CMTimeGetSeconds(duration)
                            print(durationInSecond)
                            mediaItem.videoURL = videoData!
                            self.mediaArray.append(mediaItem)
                            print(self.mediaArray.count)


                        }

                    })
                })
            }

        }
        else{
            //showAllertToImportImage()//A function to show alert
        }
    }
}
```

This issue is on the mobile not the simulator

Comment: Not sure this will help but I figured I'd pass it along just in case: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32445471/file-couldnt-be-opened-because-you-dont-have-permission

Comment: Didn't work unfortunately, this is on the mobile too, not the simulator

Comment: I still have this issue :|

Comment: hey AndrewS. you are solve this problem or not ?

Comment: No I have not unfortunately

Comment: hey AndrewS. you are solve this problem or not ?

Comment: No I have not, I have just gone ahead and used the default apple gives for doing this