# In Xcode when I try to upload a video file to firebase I am unable to?

Tags: swift, xcode, firebase, permissions

For my app I have fetched the videos from the photo library on my phone and have created a collection view of all the videos. I am able to get the correct file path for each video when I go to upload it to Firebase but it won't let me because I don't have permission to view it.

[picture of error in debugger console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NDubG.png)

I know the function to upload the file to Firebase works because if I access the videos using ImagePickerController and go directly to the video in my photo library I can get the URL from there and upload it.

So to summarize, how do I grant my Xcode project permission to open a video file so the URL can be uploaded to Firebase?

Any help to solve this problem is greatly appreciated!

Comment: did you try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32445471/file-couldnt-be-opened-because-you-dont-have-permission?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa

Comment: Can you verify if you have this key `NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription`  in info.plist

Comment: Please put the error message into your question as text, not a picture.

Comment: Yes I have the "Privacy - Photo Library Usage Description" inside of the p list, which is why I am confused

Comment: Here is the error as it appears in the console

Comment: Unable to load data: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=257 "The file “IMG_7646.MOV” couldn’t be opened because you don’t have permission to view it." UserInfo={NSFilePath=/var/mobile/Media/DCIM/117APPLE/IMG_7646.MOV, NSUnderlyingError=0x1c06508c0 {Error Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=1 "Operation not permitted"}}