# Xcode run fails because I don't have permission to open file

Tags: ios, xcode

I get this error every time I try to run my app in Xcode 7: "The file “[AppName]” couldn’t be opened because you don’t have permission to view it."

[image]

I have tried EVERY suggestion in the previously answered question found here: ["The file "MyApp.app" couldn't be opened because you don't have permission to view it" when running app in Xcode 6 Beta 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24924809/the-file-myapp-app-couldnt-be-opened-because-you-dont-have-permission-to-vi)

Such suggestions were:

- deleting derived data
- cleaning and running
- repairing permission on my disk
- rebooting
- changing the permissions of my files in finder with get info
- changing the value of the "Compiler for C/C++/Objective-C" to the Default Compiler.
- changing the executable file name to "$(EXECUTABLE_NAME)"
- cleaning the build folder
- creating a new project with the same name and replacing the info.plist file with the new one
- clicking "update to recommended settings"
- changing the architectures to the standard architectures
- matching the architectures with the valid architectures
- changing Build Active Architecture Only from No to Yes and vice versa
- changing the bundle identifier to com.myCompany.$(PRODUCT_NAME)

Still nothing has worked! :(

I'm not using cocoa pods.

This was a project I had been working on before I updated to Xcode 7 and Swift 2. After I updated Xcode, and after I converted the syntax to Swift 2 I began getting this error.

Comment: Refer to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50167291/6521116) with a good summary of this issue.