# Xcode 7.0.1 couldn’t be opened because you don’t have permission to view it

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

Problem is simple. Can't open this project because of permission issue.
Take a look screenshot.

[image]

What I did before asking this question

1. Completely deleted Derived data folder using alias
   alias purgeallbuilds='rm -rf ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/*'
2. Changed Build settings > Change Compiler for C/C++/Objective-C to Default compiler.
3. Changed project folder's permissions for myself to read+write, and enclosed folders too.
4. Changed Standard architectures (armv7, arm64) and changed "Default Compiler (Apple LLVM 6.0)" compiler settings.

Using
Xcode 7.0.1

Any other workarounds?

Comment: Is this code in version control?  I had this happen and the easiest way to solve it for me was to go into the directory, delete everything (aside from .git, of course), and then just `git checkout -- .`

Comment: Yes, code hosted in here https://github.com/nikita-leonov/ReactiveCocoaPlayground, checked out using SSH clone url

Comment: Charles A's suggestion worked for me on Xcode 7.2.1 with an old project. Thank you Charles... I'm not sure I ever would have figured this out myself.

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["The file "MyApp.app" couldn't be opened because you don't have permission to view it" when running app in Xcode 6 Beta 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24924809/the-file-myapp-app-couldnt-be-opened-because-you-dont-have-permission-to-vi)