# Unable to run "The file “***.app” couldn’t be opened because you don’t have permission to view it"

Tags: swift, xcode, compiler-errors, swift3, xcode8

I'm unable to run the app in simulator and devices it's showing the same error, i did search in stackoverflow , did get a solution till now, spending more than an a hour now.

Following solution i had gone through

1. cleaning derived data
2. product clean
3. replacing info.plist
4. renaming project name
5. Editing the permission on the folder of the project
6. checking architectures
7. changed value in build options to Compiler for C/C++/Objective-C" to Default Compiler.

Is there any other solutions for it, i didn't added any new folder or files from outside also.

Comment: Change Deployment Target to 8.0 , And try.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [The file “\*\*\*.app” couldn’t be opened because you don’t have permission to view it](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34103048/the-file-app-couldn-t-be-opened-because-you-don-t-have-permission-to-view)

Comment: Refer to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50167291/6521116) with a good summary of this issue.

Answer (score 0):

How many xcode you have installed.

you can check selected version of xcode by command.
xcode-select -print-path

the you need to switch to desired version of xcode by command.

sudo xcode-select -switch /Application/Xcode.app/Contents/developer