# Not able to attach and post pdf files from "MyFiles" in iOS

Tags: ios, swift, pdf, local-files

I want to attach pdf files to my application, this pdf file is stored in "Pages" application of iOS, when I try to attach this file, I am easily able to access the pdf file URL, but when I try to send the pdf to server it gives me the following error :

> The file “12312331.pdf” couldn’t be opened because you don’t have permission to view it.

I used `UIDocumentBrowserViewController` with the desired delegate methods to get the local files,
I have already set the required keys in "`Info.plist`".

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34103048/the-file-app-couldn-t-be-opened-because-you-don-t-have-permission-to-view

Comment: @Mosbah the link which you gave is not the solution i guess, because my file is not corrupt.