# Permission denied when building app in xcode 7 - El Capitan

Tags: ios, permissions, cocoapods, xcode7, osx-elcapitan

My app was working normally but when I updated my OS to El Capitan I started to see this message

"The file “app” couldn’t be opened because you don’t have permission to view it."

I tried somethings that I saw on internet like change architectures compatibilities, check and solve permissions problems on disk utilities, nothing works

Another thing that I did before change the OS was delete every pod references from my project, but I am not sure that this could be the problem with permissions

Comment: Have you cleared the `DerivedData` folder?

Comment: I didn't find this folder here

Comment: @chedabob I found it. But also didn't help me =/

Comment: Refer to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50167291/6521116) with a good summary of this issue.