# my app don’t have permission xcode 7

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I am new to objective c. I deleted all my classes in 'Compile Sources', after that I got error: "The file {my app name} couldn’t be opened because you don’t have permission to view it.". Other than that, my app worked fine. I tried many solutions but they did not work

**I have tried:**

Replacing my info.plist

Deleting Derived Data

Editing the permission on the folder of the project

Changing "Compiler for C/C++/Objective-C" to Default in Build Settings

Checking my architectures

Cleaning My Project

**Thanks for your help!**

**Update:** I am not able to run app in simulator as well as device

**Edit:** added all .m file to 'Compile Sources' and got error like this:

```
 ld: entry point (_main) undefined. for architecture arm64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Edit: created new project and copy classes to new project. again error

```
 Ld /Users/sherzod/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/maktub-grrvlbarzrzucfdjeuhroypwrwpr/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/maktub.app/maktub normal arm64
    cd /Volumes/Data/Projects/maktub
    export IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET=6.0
    export PATH="/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang -arch arm64 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS9.1.sdk -L/Users/sherzod/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/maktub-grrvlbarzrzucfdjeuhroypwrwpr/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos -F/Users/sherzod/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/maktub-grrvlbarzrzucfdjeuhroypwrwpr/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos -filelist /Users/sherzod/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/maktub-grrvlbarzrzucfdjeuhroypwrwpr/Build/Intermediates/maktub.build/Debug-iphoneos/maktub.build/Objects-normal/arm64/maktub.LinkFileList -Xlinker -rpath -Xlinker @executable_path/Frameworks -miphoneos-version-min=6.0 -dead_strip -ObjC -lCocoaAsyncSocket -framework CFNetwork -framework Security -fobjc-arc -fobjc-link-runtime -lsqlite3 -lz.1 -lPods-maktub -Xlinker -dependency_info -Xlinker /Users/sherzod/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/maktub-grrvlbarzrzucfdjeuhroypwrwpr/Build/Intermediates/maktub.build/Debug-iphoneos/maktub.build/Objects-normal/arm64/maktub_dependency_info.dat -o /Users/sherzod/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/maktub-grrvlbarzrzucfdjeuhroypwrwpr/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/maktub.app/maktub

duplicate symbol _key in:
    /Users/sherzod/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/maktub-grrvlbarzrzucfdjeuhroypwrwpr/Build/Intermediates/maktub.build/Debug-iphoneos/maktub.build/Objects-normal/arm64/CheckCodeController.o
    /Users/sherzod/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/maktub-grrvlbarzrzucfdjeuhroypwrwpr/Build/Intermediates/maktub.build/Debug-iphoneos/maktub.build/Objects-normal/arm64/SettingController.o
duplicate symbol _iv in:
    /Users/sherzod/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/maktub-grrvlbarzrzucfdjeuhroypwrwpr/Build/Intermediates/maktub.build/Debug-iphoneos/maktub.build/Objects-normal/arm64/CheckCodeController.o
    /Users/sherzod/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/maktub-grrvlbarzrzucfdjeuhroypwrwpr/Build/Intermediates/maktub.build/Debug-iphoneos/maktub.build/Objects-normal/arm64/SettingController.o
duplicate symbol _key in:
    /Users/sherzod/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/maktub-grrvlbarzrzucfdjeuhroypwrwpr/Build/Intermediates/maktub.build/Debug-iphoneos/maktub.build/Objects-normal/arm64/CheckCodeController.o
    /Users/sherzod/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/maktub-grrvlbarzrzucfdjeuhroypwrwpr/Build/Intermediates/maktub.build/Debug-iphoneos/maktub.build/Objects-normal/arm64/IntroController.o
duplicate symbol _iv in:
    /Users/sherzod/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/maktub-grrvlbarzrzucfdjeuhroypwrwpr/Build/Intermediates/maktub.build/Debug-iphoneos/maktub.build/Objects-normal/arm64/CheckCodeController.o
    /Users/sherzod/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/maktub-grrvlbarzrzucfdjeuhroypwrwpr/Build/Intermediates/maktub.build/Debug-iphoneos/maktub.build/Objects-normal/arm64/IntroController.o
duplicate symbol _key in:
    /Users/sherzod/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/maktub-grrvlbarzrzucfdjeuhroypwrwpr/Build/Intermediates/maktub.build/Debug-iphoneos/maktub.build/Objects-normal/arm64/CheckCodeController.o
    /Users/sherzod/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/maktub-grrvlbarzrzucfdjeuhroypwrwpr/Build/Intermediates/maktub.build/Debug-iphoneos/maktub.build/Objects-normal/arm64/AppDelegate.o
duplicate symbol _iv in:
    /Users/sherzod/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/maktub-grrvlbarzrzucfdjeuhroypwrwpr/Build/Intermediates/maktub.build/Debug-iphoneos/maktub.build/Objects-normal/arm64/CheckCodeController.o
    /Users/sherzod/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/maktub-grrvlbarzrzucfdjeuhroypwrwpr/Build/Intermediates/maktub.build/Debug-iphoneos/maktub.build/Objects-normal/arm64/AppDelegate.o
duplicate symbol _key in:
    /Users/sherzod/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/maktub-grrvlbarzrzucfdjeuhroypwrwpr/Build/Intermediates/maktub.build/Debug-iphoneos/maktub.build/Objects-normal/arm64/CheckCodeController.o
    /Users/sherzod/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/maktub-grrvlbarzrzucfdjeuhroypwrwpr/Build/Intermediates/maktub.build/Debug-iphoneos/maktub.build/Objects-normal/arm64/ContactController.o
duplicate symbol _iv in:
    /Users/sherzod/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/maktub-grrvlbarzrzucfdjeuhroypwrwpr/Build/Intermediates/maktub.build/Debug-iphoneos/maktub.build/Objects-normal/arm64/CheckCodeController.o
    /Users/sherzod/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/maktub-grrvlbarzrzucfdjeuhroypwrwpr/Build/Intermediates/maktub.build/Debug-iphoneos/maktub.build/Objects-normal/arm64/ContactController.o
duplicate symbol _key in:
    /Users/sherzod/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/maktub-grrvlbarzrzucfdjeuhroypwrwpr/Build/Intermediates/maktub.build/Debug-iphoneos/maktub.build/Objects-normal/arm64/CheckCodeController.o
    /Users/sherzod/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/maktub-grrvlbarzrzucfdjeuhroypwrwpr/Build/Intermediates/maktub.build/Debug-iphoneos/maktub.build/Objects-normal/arm64/RegisterController.o
duplicate symbol _iv in:
    /Users/sherzod/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/maktub-grrvlbarzrzucfdjeuhroypwrwpr/Build/Intermediates/maktub.build/Debug-iphoneos/maktub.build/Objects-normal/arm64/CheckCodeController.o
    /Users/sherzod/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/maktub-grrvlbarzrzucfdjeuhroypwrwpr/Build/Intermediates/maktub.build/Debug-iphoneos/maktub.build/Objects-normal/arm64/RegisterController.o
duplicate symbol _key in:
    /Users/sherzod/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/maktub-grrvlbarzrzucfdjeuhroypwrwpr/Build/Intermediates/maktub.build/Debug-iphoneos/maktub.build/Objects-normal/arm64/CheckCodeController.o
    /Users/sherzod/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/maktub-grrvlbarzrzucfdjeuhroypwrwpr/Build/Intermediates/maktub.build/Debug-iphoneos/maktub.build/Objects-normal/arm64/AESCrypto.o
duplicate symbol _iv in:
    /Users/sherzod/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/maktub-grrvlbarzrzucfdjeuhroypwrwpr/Build/Intermediates/maktub.build/Debug-iphoneos/maktub.build/Objects-normal/arm64/CheckCodeController.o
    /Users/sherzod/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/maktub-grrvlbarzrzucfdjeuhroypwrwpr/Build/Intermediates/maktub.build/Debug-iphoneos/maktub.build/Objects-normal/arm64/AESCrypto.o
duplicate symbol _key in:
    /Users/sherzod/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/maktub-grrvlbarzrzucfdjeuhroypwrwpr/Build/Intermediates/maktub.build/Debug-iphoneos/maktub.build/Objects-normal/arm64/CheckCodeController.o
    /Users/sherzod/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/maktub-grrvlbarzrzucfdjeuhroypwrwpr/Build/Intermediates/maktub.build/Debug-iphoneos/maktub.build/Objects-normal/arm64/SetNameController.o
duplicate symbol _iv in:
    /Users/sherzod/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/maktub-grrvlbarzrzucfdjeuhroypwrwpr/Build/Intermediates/maktub.build/Debug-iphoneos/maktub.build/Objects-normal/arm64/CheckCodeController.o
    /Users/sherzod/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/maktub-grrvlbarzrzucfdjeuhroypwrwpr/Build/Intermediates/maktub.build/Debug-iphoneos/maktub.build/Objects-normal/arm64/SetNameController.o
duplicate symbol _key in:
    /Users/sherzod/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/maktub-grrvlbarzrzucfdjeuhroypwrwpr/Build/Intermediates/maktub.build/Debug-iphoneos/maktub.build/Objects-normal/arm64/CheckCodeController.o
    /Users/sherzod/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/maktub-grrvlbarzrzucfdjeuhroypwrwpr/Build/Intermediates/maktub.build/Debug-iphoneos/maktub.build/Objects-normal/arm64/ChatController.o
duplicate symbol _iv in:
    /Users/sherzod/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/maktub-grrvlbarzrzucfdjeuhroypwrwpr/Build/Intermediates/maktub.build/Debug-iphoneos/maktub.build/Objects-normal/arm64/CheckCodeController.o
    /Users/sherzod/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/maktub-grrvlbarzrzucfdjeuhroypwrwpr/Build/Intermediates/maktub.build/Debug-iphoneos/maktub.build/Objects-normal/arm64/ChatController.o
duplicate symbol _key in:
    /Users/sherzod/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/maktub-grrvlbarzrzucfdjeuhroypwrwpr/Build/Intermediates/maktub.build/Debug-iphoneos/maktub.build/Objects-normal/arm64/CheckCodeController.o
    /Users/sherzod/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/maktub-grrvlbarzrzucfdjeuhroypwrwpr/Build/Intermediates/maktub.build/Debug-iphoneos/maktub.build/Objects-normal/arm64/GroupController.o
duplicate symbol _iv in:
    /Users/sherzod/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/maktub-grrvlbarzrzucfdjeuhroypwrwpr/Build/Intermediates/maktub.build/Debug-iphoneos/maktub.build/Objects-normal/arm64/CheckCodeController.o
    /Users/sherzod/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/maktub-grrvlbarzrzucfdjeuhroypwrwpr/Build/Intermediates/maktub.build/Debug-iphoneos/maktub.build/Objects-normal/arm64/GroupController.o
duplicate symbol _key in:
    /Users/sherzod/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/maktub-grrvlbarzrzucfdjeuhroypwrwpr/Build/Intermediates/maktub.build/Debug-iphoneos/maktub.build/Objects-normal/arm64/CheckCodeController.o
    /Users/sherzod/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/maktub-grrvlbarzrzucfdjeuhroypwrwpr/Build/Intermediates/maktub.build/Debug-iphoneos/maktub.build/Objects-normal/arm64/GlobalMethod.o
duplicate symbol _iv in:
    /Users/sherzod/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/maktub-grrvlbarzrzucfdjeuhroypwrwpr/Build/Intermediates/maktub.build/Debug-iphoneos/maktub.build/Objects-normal/arm64/CheckCodeController.o
    /Users/sherzod/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/maktub-grrvlbarzrzucfdjeuhroypwrwpr/Build/Intermediates/maktub.build/Debug-iphoneos/maktub.build/Objects-normal/arm64/GlobalMethod.o
ld: 20 duplicate symbols for architecture arm64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Comment: Could this be helpful? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24924809/the-file-myapp-app-couldnt-be-opened-because-you-dont-have-permission-to-vi

Comment: @GenieWanted thanks answer but i did any advise and not found solusion

Comment: When I had this issue, I was able to fix it by following "Magreth deGraaf"'s answer.. Can you just give it a try?

Comment: Refer to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50167291/6521116) with a good summary of this issue.

Answer (score 0):

**Solution 1:**

select info

```
Enter Bundle name As : ${PRODUCT_NAME}

Executable file : ${EXECUTABLE_NAME}
```

**Solution 2:**

Just figured out it can be another problem. It can happen that your Main.m file isn't included anymore in the `Build Phases -> compile sources`. You'll get the same error. You can just re-add it by clicking the plus and selecting the file 
from the dialog.

**Solution 3:**

Go up to the folder containing the project in your Finder.

Right `Click > Get Info`

Go to the bottom of the Info pane, and click the little lock, type in your password when prompted.

Then, change permissions for yourself to read+write.

Click the little gear below, and apply to all enclosed items.

Close the lock once you are finished!

If this doesn't work, Change the value of "`Compiler for C/C++/Objective-C`" to Default Compiler under BUILD OPTIONS

May be it will help you.