# Don't have permission to access video file path in swift

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

Getting this error when uploading file to server

```
Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=257 "The file “IMG_0011.MOV”   couldn’t be opened because you don’t have permission to view it." UserInfo={NSFilePath=/var/mobile/Media/DCIM/100APPLE/IMG_0011.MOV, NSUnderlyingError=0x13b157510 {Error Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=1  "Operation not permitted"}}
```

My code for converting path to NSDATA is:

```
 let videoURL = User.sharedInstance.arrRoomGalleryVideos.objectAtIndex(index) as? NSURL
            var movieData: NSData?
            do {
                let video = try NSData(contentsOfURL: videoURL!, options: .DataReadingMappedIfSafe)
               // print("video", video)
                multipartFormData.appendBodyPart(data: video, name: "video_path[]", fileName: strVidName, mimeType: "mp4/.mov")
            } catch {
                print(error)
                return
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this -

Navigate to Build Settings -> Go to Build Options and change the value of the `"Compiler for C/C++/Objective-C"` to `Default Compiler.`

For more solutions check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24924809/the-file-myapp-app-couldnt-be-opened-because-you-dont-have-permission-to-vi)

Comment: problem is in device not in simulator