# Xcode says "You don't have permission" when trying to run. Tried a lot of solutions from here

Tags: c++, ios, xcode, react-native

I found many questions on here asking for the same thing. I have tried all of them but I am still getting this error. I created everything from scratch again and was running well until I deleted the data from "DerivedData" folder and now this permissions alert error came back.

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SEJgQ.png)

I have been trying following things for a week now:

1. I have tried copying this project to a new folder. Didn't work.
2. I changed every permission to my folder structure to be read & write to every user.
3. Product -> Clean.
4. Renaming the app.
5. Compiler for C, C++, Objective-C is "Default compiler Apple LLVM 8.0)
6. Build Settings > Architectures -> to Standard Architectures
7. Replaced Info.plist from a newly created project.

Xcode version 8.1.

I see that one of the similar questions were tagged as a duplicate. But I am really stuck here for a week. I have tried everything from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24924809/the-file-myapp-app-couldnt-be-opened-because-you-dont-have-permission-to-vi)

And a lot of others that I found online.

I would really appreciate any help on this. I couldn't finish my project because of just this permisssion issue.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: can you post the screenShot,  alternatively you can create a new project and drag and drop all files into new project

Comment: Could it be related to your Apple ID? Have you changed the password of an Apple ID, or have you removed from some kind of group?

Comment: @Dhiru I did create a new project, dragged and dropped all .js files, then the ios folder. Tried a few different scenarios with copying. It's still showing the same thing. Updated the question with a screenshot.

Comment: @mattliu I haven't changed the password or any group since I created it a couple of months ago. Until a couple of weeks ago I was able to archive the project and send new versions to testers using the HockeySDK. Not sure what is happening here, I am really stuck.