# Getting " App couldn’t be opened because you don’t have permission to view it. " after converting project code from swift 2.2 to swift 3.0

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, swift3, xcode8

Recently I opened my old project( which is written in Swift 2.2 and project created on Xcode 7.2.) in latest XCode 8.3.1. Xcode asked me for converting the project into swift 3 as XCode 8.3.1 not supporting older version of swift I clicked on convert project and some changes are done automatically some Pods I updated by pod install command and some manually added new swift3 classes. Mostly all viewController's class's syntax changed manually to swift3. It takes two days to build successfully project in Xcode 8.3.1. Now when I run my project on device or simulator it shows me error like:

> The file “AppName.app” couldn’t be opened because you don’t have
>   permission to view it.

I searched a lot on StackOverflow and google and found some solutions.
I have tried:

- Replacing my info.plist
- Deleting Derived Data
- Duplicating my app
- Editing the permission on the folder of the project Changing
- "Compiler for C/C++/Objective-C" to Default in Build Settings
- Checking my architectures Cleaning My Project
- And there are no any physical folders also
- Entered Bundle name As : ${PRODUCT_NAME}
- Changed Executable file : ${EXECUTABLE_NAME}

But nothing is working please tell me what should I do? I have a backup of the project should I use old Xcode to run project every time? Please it's a request do not close this question as no solutions working provided by older question's posted on StackOverflow and this question is different also because of swift3. Thanks in advance. :)

Comment: Give it a try -- https://www.tec20.co.uk/resolving-xcode-dont-permission-error/

Comment: Refer to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50167291/6521116) with a good summary of this issue.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, a simple Product -> Clean worked great.