# The file couldn’t be opened because you don’t have permission to view it. xcode

Tags: objective-c, xcode8

I renamed my xcode project from "SomeName" to "Tenant App". It is building fine but while running it encounters "**The file “Tenant App” couldn’t be opened because you don’t have permission to view it.**" error.

My compiler is set to default and every directory is duly set. Below is link to the image for corresponding error.

I request to all to help me here. Thanks all in advance

Comment: Refer to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50167291/6521116) with a good summary of this issue.