# macOS Xcode9.1 how to get the permission of reading file?

Tags: swift, macos

I am using the following code to read the content of a text file.

```
let str = try! String(contentsOfFile:"/Users/my/Desktop/a.txt")
```

It works well until I upgraded my Xcode to 9.1 version and this line of code made the app crashed. The error is :

Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=257 "The file a.txt” couldn’t be opened because you don’t have permission to view it."

How can I get the permission to read the file?

Comment: If the app is sandboxed you have only access to the data in the container. But this behavior is not particularly related to Xcode 9.1

Comment: You are right ! thanks a lot for your reminding, I checked the Capabilities of the Target, and the sandbox switch is on.

Comment: Refer to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50167291/6521116) with a good summary of this issue.