# The file “AppName” couldn’t be opened because you don’t have permission to view it You don’t have permission.` when running app in Xcode 10.1

Tags: ios, xcode, permissions

I am getting issue when I am trying to run the app in iPhone and iPad. I am getting:

> The file AppName couldn’t be opened because you don’t have permission to view it. You don’t have permission.`

when running app in Xcode 10.1.

- Restarting my computer
- Deleting all Derived Data from Organizer in Xcode
- Repairing permissions on my drive

Any one have idea for this issue how to resolve this I also tried the different way to get running code but still getting same problem.

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["The file "MyApp.app" couldn't be opened because you don't have permission to view it" when running app in Xcode 6 Beta 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24924809/the-file-myapp-app-couldnt-be-opened-because-you-dont-have-permission-to-vi)

Answer (score 0):

go to Window - Device and Simulators and remove all your devices. Then pair again.

If not helped - restart iOS device too.