# Xcode error: The file couldn't be opened because you don't have permission to view it

Tags: xcode, macos, macos-catalina

**The file couldn't be opened because you don't have permission to view it**

Today I turned on my computer and discovered that **all** my projects show this error for each file in a project. Some of my projects have third-party libs, some don't. I checked all answers in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24924809/the-file-myapp-app-couldnt-be-opened-because-you-dont-have-permission-to-vi), but none of that helped. Also I tried to reinstall Xcode following [this article](https://medium.com/faun/macos-catalina-xcode-homebrew-gems-developer-headaches-cf7b1edf10b7), it also didn't have an effect.

Of course I tried to reboot my mac and I changed permissions as Xcode asked but it didn't help. As I discovered it is a very common error that can occur for very different reasons. Yesterday everything worked fine, I didn't update macOS or Xcode, but it started getting these errors after turning on the computer.

System: macOS Catalina 10.15.1

Xcode: 11.2.1 (after reinstall, before that Xcode had lower version)

[image]

Answer (score 8):

I too had the same file permission issue to my existing project after updating to Catalina.

Resolved it by granting xcode the Full Disk Access.
Got to

> System Preferences --> Security & Privacy --> Privacy --> Full Disk
>   Access --> Add Xcode & also in Files & Folders  --> Add Xcode

Comment: did not fix the issue on OSX10.15.4/Xcode11.4.1 even after completely rebooting the computer after making the changes above.

Comment: "last night a dj saved my life", I mean your answer! Thanks

Answer (score -1):

open the project again instead of choosing it from recents when launching xcode.