# Xcode: Do not have permission to view app

Tags: ios, xcode, kivy

I am new to Xcode.

I am getting a strange error message when try to I build my Xcode project to my iPhone. I get the following error message (despite the build being successful):

[image: Error when I attempt to build project to iPhone]

However, I don't have this issue when I build the project to a simulator - it will run my app fine.

I have gone into the /Library/Developer folder (the one that contains chessclock.app) and ensured that all files have a Read & Write permission. I have also made sure that all the relevant Xcode files have Read & Write permission. I also made sure that my Mac trusts the iPhone - and vice-versa - and have made sure that everything is up-to-date. Still this issue persists!

What can I try next?

**Specifications**

- Xcode version 12.0.1
- iPhone SE running iOS version 14.0.1
- MacBook Air running macOS Catalina version 10.15.7

I have built the app in Kivy (Python) and used kivy-ios to create the Xcode project

Comment: Well written question. Maybe [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24924809/the-file-myapp-app-couldnt-be-opened-because-you-dont-have-permission-to-vi) can help? Let me know.

Comment: Try deleting your DerivedData folder and building again.

Comment: @BenMyers and Alex Walczak, thank you both for your comments! I have solved the issue. Turns out my Mac was uploading some of the project files to my iCloud, which was causing the permission issues. I turned this off, and made sure I had all my files saved locally, and abra kadabra it worked! Thanks again for both your comments

Comment: Glad you got it worked out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved.

Some of my project files (my font files) were automatically uploaded to my iCloud - this was causing the permission issues, as I think I wasn't allowed to save an app to my phone that has access to my iCloud. After downloading the files and saving them locally, the app ran on my iPhone.